# Magento fetch category name somehow

Tags: magento, categories

Anyone who can help me?

I have a product template with custom header images displayed. It works as follows:
When I add a static block with pagename and then -header behind it then that static block (identifier) displayed on the page. This block does not exist then it shows the default-header static block.

What needs to be done is grab main category name (-header) and place it in the custom 1column-product.phtml template I have where the default-header (identifier) is being loaded.

line 77:

```
// GET DEFAULT HEADER
echo Mage::getModel(‘cms/block’)-> load(‘default-header’)-> getContent();
```

**‘default-header’ needs to be ‘categoryname-header’**

I don’t think it is that hard to do but I'm not a coder :(

Total code:

```
<header>    
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
<section id="subtop" class="clearfix">
<div class="slideContainer clearfix">

<?php
if ($this->getUrl('') == $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array('_current'=>true, '_use_rewrite'=>true)) ) {
// HOMEPAGE IS TRUE
$cmsBlock = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('flexslider')->getContent();
if($cmsBlock) {
echo $cmsBlock;
}
}else{


echo '<div class="pghead clearfix ABC">';           
if(Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('default-header')->getContent()){
// GET DEFAULT HEADER
echo Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('default-header')->getContent();
}
// promotion banner
echo '</div>';  
if(Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('promotion')->getContent()){ ?>
<div class="promotion">
<div class="container">
    <?=Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('promotion')->getContent(); ?>
</div>
</div>
<? } // promotion banner

} //Flexslider ?>
</div><!-- slidecontainer -->
```

Comment: does anyone knows how to do this ?

Comment: anyone who can push me into the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

```
//if you are in category or product page
    $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category'); 
//or load category if you are in pages other than product or category page
// $currentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(12);
    $blockName = $currentCategory->getName().'-header';
    echo Mage::getModel(‘cms/block’)-> load($blockName)-> getContent();
```

You can load current category using Magento registry if you are in the product or category page. If it's in other pages then you need to load category by other means.